# PHP Encryption / USB key

Tags: php, encryption, usb

I've got an application where users save sensitive data. At the moment they have to enter a long encryption key, which is then saved localy in a cookie (the cooke data is encrypted).

So when they save or retrive data, said data is either encrypted or decrypted with the key in the previously mentioned cookie. This way the key is not saved on the server itself.

I've been looking into using USB-Dongles, so users don't have to enter the passphrase and no sensitvie data has to be sotored locally, even if that data is encrypted itself. Has anyone had any experence with this sort of thing.The closet thing a found were dongles used as software keys. Does anyone know of USB dongles where a shared key can be saved and then used? Or should I be using some other form of encryption where every user has a uniqe key?

Thanks for any inputs/ideas!

Comment: What if the user clears their browser cookies?

Comment: Then said user has to enter the encryption key again...

Answer (score 1):

This is something I do frequently for desktop applications. It works beautifully for a wide variety of programming languages, and encryption methods: even though each language requires a separate implementation, it is easy enough to store all the keys in a common area, and desktop/server apps have the ability to scan removable media to detect if an appropriate USB key is available.

It is doubtful you will be able to use this for a web client *(web server - yes! web client - no... which is probably how most will interact with your web site)*. Unless your website has some desktop portion that has access to the file system, you will not be able to load/save data from the file system without user intervention. (Cookies can be annoying and frustrating, but they are there for a reason.)